# Drupal's category (taxonomy) name of article (node)?

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

Developing my custom Drupal's theme. it will contain custom node.tpl.php file.

How can i get and print related taxonomy names of selected node?

Tnx in adv!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Doh, my apologies, I'm just now seeing the Drupal 7 tag, specifically. It appears this thread has some possible solutions: http://drupal.org/node/909968

With D6 (not 100% about D7) In the node's template .php files (and similarly, in a view or most anywhere you have access to a node's properties with custom PHP, like a View or Block), you can use the following:

```
// returns array of taxonomy objects for given node
$tax_terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);

// prints each term name
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax) {
    print $tax->name;
}
```

Also, there's a few useful Drupal functions for cases like this:

```
// print_r's all properties of a given node, similar to devel
dpr($node);

// using this in the above 'for' look will give you all properties of each taxonomy object
dpr($tax);
```

[Here's a website](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/02-10-2007/hugely-useful-hugely-undocumented) that lists a few more of these functions.